# Gmail API's history.list incorrect messagesAdded value

Tags: gmail-api

In the [history list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) endpoint is recommended to use specific change-type fields like `messagesAdded` rather than the `messages` field.

However I've noticed that when receiving an email with an attachment or without body (just the subject) the `messagesAdded` field is empty while the `messages` field has an entry.

Is this the correct behaviour? I was expecting the `messagesAdded` key with a value as well.

Comment: What is the complete request that you are doing?

Comment: This is the request I'm doing:

`curl -XGET -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?startHistoryId=HISTORYID&maxResults=1'`

And the response I'm receiving contains only the `messages` key but not the `messagesAdded` key. 

The `HISTORYID` is retrieved from a Google Mail PUSH notification, I'm following the [Push Notifications guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

Comment: Found a currently [open bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761652) which describes exactly the same behaviour

Comment: How did you resolve this in the end?